# How to Logout or Switch another account in .Asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

[The Full Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82erF.png)

There is no such issue, but i wanted to add Logout button and Switch to another account button to work.

Comment: What authentication provider are you using? If you're using the SQL membership and role providers for .net then Yes you can execute a log off and even execute a log on. But this ability will depend on which authentication provider you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code should the authentification form when Login and password are correct the Con session variable will get the value from the Login field
`Session["Con"]=textbox1.text //Textbox1 is for login` `
on the onclick event in disconnect button

```
Session["Con"]=0
```

I guess you should allow only people with Session["Con"] != 0 wich are the people who succeeded to connect to enter other forms .

```
if(Session["Con"] != 0){
       Response.Redirect("LoginForm.aspx")
    }
```

According to my modest experience in asp this is the approche i would use to make the disconnect and connect buttons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).